# Streaming Images from native C++ to a web browser

Tags: c++, html, server-side

I am trying to figure out how difficult it will be to achieve this. I have C/C++ drivers to interface with a machine vision camera. All it does is grab frames from the camera at 14 fps as a `.tif`. I want to display this image stream in a browser.

My background is in hardware, drivers and applications, not in web development. How much trouble am I getting in to? How easy would it be to create a video stream from the images, and feed it to a video player on the webpage?

Comment: Does it have to be a fluent "real" videostream or is fast image switching between the .tif´s alright too (which is easier, but could look a bit laggy)?

Comment: And can you get the imagedata from the camera to your program directly without reading it from a file?

Comment: I can, I grab it straight from the stream coming in through ethernet from the camera. 5 fps should be quick enough.